# Crystal Reports with VB6 .dsr file

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

A couple of days ago I posted a problem I was having awhile trying to have multiple vertical columns on my old Crystal Reports. I was able to solver that problem editing the query and making it to return the number of results I wanted to make 4 labels.

The main goal of this VB6 project is to print 4 vertical labels of a single product.

I don't know If I am doing anything wrong or even If I need to change the VB6 code, but if any of you had a similar problem (even though I am using old school software) or any tip to give me I would appreciate.

This project will be used on the (also) old VB6 where I have to import the .rpt file and VB6 converts it into a .dsr file. I don't know if it loses the possibility to make 4 labels, but after I import it, it looks like this:

On Crystal Reports (perfect):

[image]

On VB6 (it loses the duplicate rows):

[image]

Thank you so much in advance.